# Integrated authentication and external access

Tags: asp.net, iis

Question - Will I be able to access a Asp.net website on IIS 7 with integrated windows authentication enabled from outside the domain?

Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - browser will typically prompt for your windows credentials. User name has to be provided as `[Domain Name]/[Login Name]` format where domain name will be target domain (i.e. domain known (and trusted) by your web server).

Comment: I have this site with integrated authentication enabled with active directory.Even after providing the credentials with domain name /username it always shows 401 error page for windows authenticated pages. Any advice. this article says - Integrated Windows authentication does not work over HTTP proxy connections.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/523ae943-5e6a-4200-9103-9808baa00157.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @dotnetrocks - thats correct - integrated authentication won't work over HTTP proxies. As far as your problem is concerned, you need to ascertain cause of problem - it could have been because proxy but that you can quickly figure out by accessing the site from the web server itself. If it is proxy related then you may try basic authentication with SSL (for securing credentials).